# Return one column values as list from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

Is it possible to return data structure like this directly from MSSQL ?

```
public class MyClass
{
       public int Id {get; set;}
       public int List<int> AnotherIds {get; set;}
}
```

I need this to retrieve data to list if Id is a duplicate
For example:
Select * FROM MyTable

```
--------------------
|   Id    | AnthId |
|   1     |   1    |
|   1     |   2    |
|   1     |   3    |
|   2     |   1    |
|   2     |   2    |
|   2     |   3    |
|   2     |   4    |
--------------------
```

Result will be List of 2 entities:
MyClass[0]{1, [1,2,3]}
MyClass[1]{2, [1,2,3,4]}

Comment: Yes it is. Use a PIVOT

Comment: have to know your db structure to answer this. include your schema.

Comment: It qould be easier to use an ORM like entity framework or return a data table and parse it in code. Any T-SQL solution will force you to do some work on code anyway since there is no concept of List in sql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I'm including an example you can copy/paste into your query window and using this example build your SQL to return desired data:

```
declare @tbl table(ID int, AnotherID int)
declare @aa varchar (200)
declare @result table(ID int, AnotherIDs varchar(200))

set @aa = ''

insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(1,1)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(1,2)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID)Values(1,3)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(1,4)

insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(2,1)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(2,2)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(2,3)
insert into @tbl (ID, AnotherID) Values(2,4)

--select * from @tbl


declare @i int
select @i = min(ID) from @tbl
declare @max int
select @max = max(ID) from @tbl

while @i <= @max begin

select   @aa = 
        coalesce (case when @aa = ''
                       then CAST(AnotherID as varchar)
                       else @aa + ',' + CAST(AnotherID as varchar)
                   end
                  ,'')
      from @tbl where ID=@i

insert into @result(ID, AnotherIDs)
values(@i, @aa)

        set @aa=''

set @i = @i + 1
end

select * from @result
```

Result looks like this:
**ID**   **AnotherIDs**
1   1,2,3,4
2   1,2,3,4

Comment: In this way i should parse string in c#, I dont think, that it is the best solution, but thanks